# Show post object of any page in frontend

Tags: plugins, posts, hooks

I want to see the content of the `$post` object in the front end. I want to do it via `functions.php`.

What I'm doing in `function.php` is:

```
global $post;
print_r($post);
```

But nothing shows up in the frontend. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because in functions.php, it is too early to just run the print_r(), you may run it within a [init hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) like this:

Placing it inside theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_trace' );
function test_trace() {
  global $post;
  print_r($post);
}
```

Comment: I have tried with init hook. But nothing is showing. I am confused.

Comment: What page are you showing? Front page? Single post? What is your settings in settings > reading?